# Reading CSV file

Tags: java, csv

I just wanted to read another file called "data.csv" and was wondering if I can use the same layout I have for reading the contents of the ambulance.csv? I'm trying to print the output of both the contents onto the console.

contents of data.csv

```
id  x.location  y.location  status  ambulance
1       17          19      Assigned    A64
2       50          50     Completed    
3       78          29      Pending 
4       97          12     Pending  
5       27          17    Pending   
6       28          17    Pending   
7       67          2     Pending   
8       3           99    Pending   
9      30          81     Pending   
10     49           50    Pending
```

contents of ambulance.csv

```
    id  x.location  y.location  status  patient
    A7       17        25   Responding   2
    A42      9         31   At Scene     1
    A117     1          1   At Station
```

Code to read files

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


import javax.swing.JTable;

    public class AmbulanceSystem {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            ArrayList<String[]> elements = new ArrayList<String[]>();

            String csvFile = "ambulances.csv";


            BufferedReader br = null;
             String line = "";
            String cvsSplitBy = ",";
            ArrayList<Patient[]> patients = new ArrayList<Patient[]>();
            ArrayList<Ambulance[]> ambulances = new ArrayList<Ambulance[]>();

            try {

                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    // use comma as separator
                    String[] location = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

                    System.out.println("(" + location[1] + " ," + location[2] + ")");

                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (br != null) {
                    try {
                        br.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }

        }

    }
```

My output at the moment

```
(x.location ,y.location)
(17 ,25)
(9 ,31)
(1 ,1)
```

Comment: how does your data.csv looks like

Comment: Is the csv tab-delimited instead of comma separated?

Comment: Yes, you can reuse your code and your code can read any CSV file, so for better programming make a function for reading files and use it whenever you want read an CSV file.

Comment: So i should just have one class just for reading files in particular ? Ill update my code and add in data.csv

Comment: As long as both csv files looks same just parametrize "csvFile" and you should be good

Comment: You could really use the Apache Commons CSV reader instead of re-inventing the wheel

Comment: Also to note, your separation character is a comma( ',') in the code you have listed above, if you are parsing tab separated columns then use tab('\t') as your separator.

Comment: so if i had to read data.csv can i just put a lline under buffereader called BufferedReader be = null; instead of br and then carry on with a similar style of reading ?

Comment: this is the output I get from that file at the moment (x.location ,y.location)
(17 ,25)
(9 ,31)
(1 ,1)